# Ionic framework auto login with Phonegap

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, phonegap

I created a android app with Ionic framework using Phonegap. It has a login page that authenticate from the php mysql database. The problem is each time when I open the app it is asking to login. That is when I exit the app the user credentials vanish.  So what I need is, the app must have the login details until I logout. Please suggest me a solution.

Thank You...

Comment: for this you have to store data in local storage or else make a Boolean variable and if user is login then it will be true unless user logout.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply... When I change it to local storage the app is not working. I'm new to this domain. Can U pls get me some examples?